# ADAL.JS and Offline Web App

Tags: javascript, html, azure, adal

I have a web page where I implement `ADAL.JS`.

When browsing the page via the web it works perfectly; however when I try to view it on an iPhone, and I have saved it as a shortcut on the desktop using the **Add to Homescreen** button, things go haywire.

The initial page (`index.html`) shows correctly using the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` meta tag; however, when the authentication is invoked, I am taken to a real browser window. Once redirected back to `index.html`, I am still in the separate browser window not the Web App view.

Ultimately, I want to have this as an offline web site with all page functionality running in the view produced by `apple-mobile-web-app-capable`. Any other ideas as to how to implement this are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the big problems currently existing in iOS webapps. Every link or redirection opens up in a new window. 
You can fix it changing `window.location.href` with JavaScript.

Comment: The odd thing is that if I have a file called index.html and perform a window.location.href to www.google.com i am still within the webapp. However, when ADAL redirects me to the the AD login page via a window.location the ADAL login page is in a seperate window. When you say fix it by changing window.location.href with JS..how do you suggest i do that...update the ADAL JS code to use the href property instead of window.location?

Comment: Adal.js provides a way without changing the itself. I think just writing the following into _your_ script would do it (replace %ac% by your AuthentificationContest variable): 
   `%ac%.config.displayCall=function(url){
         if (urlNavigate) {
            this.info('Navigate to:' + urlNavigate);
            window.location.href=urlNavigate;
        } else {
            this.info('Navigate url is empty');
        }
   }`

Comment: Please see my other answer...tried to tie it to this comment but too long

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be missing something...I get at urlNavigate not defined error...suggestions?

```
alert('Running Auth');
```

online = navigator.onLine;

```
authContext = new AuthenticationContext({
    tenant: azureTenant,
    clientId: azureClientId,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location,
    //redirectUri: "https://shlpkpiapi.azurewebsites.net/kpiapp/test.html"
});

authContext.config.displayCall=function(url){ 

    if (urlNavigate) 
    { 
        this.info('Navigate to:' + urlNavigate); 
        window.location.href=urlNavigate; 
    } 
    else
    { 
        this.info('Navigate url is empty'); 
    } 
}



if (authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {

    authContext.handleWindowCallback();
    var err = authContext.getLoginError();
    if (err) {
        alert('Error on callback')
    }
}
else {

    var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
    if (user) {
        //We have a user in cache and are using those credentials
        console.log('Signed in as: ' + user.userName);


    } else {
        console.log('Not signed in.')
        if (online)
        {
            alert('signing in');
            authContext.login();
        }
        else
        {
            alert('currently offline');
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: My fault: The parameter of the function should be `urlNavigate` instead of `url`.

Comment: Added my response below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I made the change and the error is gone but I don't understand how this is supposed to address the issue. When I add my page to my IPhone home screen (https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/app/test.html) and then click on the tile I am taken to the test.html page. On that page page there is an auth function that executes which uses adal.js and takes me to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2...". This shows up in the scope of my IOS Web app and has my account listed and the Use another account option. I click on my account or choose the Use another account option and I am taken to  another page that is opened in Safari.

Comment: I know this a similar problem with my own iOS webapp. You can't control foreign websites so there's currently nothing more I could suggest you. If I know a way and can implement it into my webapp, I'll let you know.

Comment: Please do. Have you used Auth0? Is this possibly the answer?